# Why Doesn't this work with Acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I have `attr_accessor :politics, :tech, :entertainment, :sports, :science, :crime, :business, :social, :nature, :other` in my post.rb (these are the tags), I want them to be virtual.

Then in the new.html.erb i have

```
<%= f.check_box :politics %>
<%= f.label :politics %>

<%= f.check_box :tech %>
<%= f.label :tech, 'Technology' %>

<%= f.check_box :entertainment %>
<%= f.label :entertainment %>

<%= f.check_box :sports %>
<%= f.label :sports %>

<%= f.check_box :science %>
<%= f.label :science %>

<%= f.check_box :crime %>
<%= f.label :crime %>

<%= f.check_box :business %>
<%= f.label :business %>

<%= f.check_box :social %>
<%= f.label :social %>

<%= f.check_box :nature %>
<%= f.label :nature %>

<%= f.check_box :other %>
<%= f.label :other %>
```

So that each are set as either true or false, then, lastly, in the post_controller.rb under `def create` i have

```
@post.tag_list << 'politics' if :politics
@post.tag_list << 'tech' if :tech
@post.tag_list << 'entertainment' if :entertainment
@post.tag_list << 'sports' if :sports
@post.tag_list << 'science' if :science
@post.tag_list << 'crime' if :crime
@post.tag_list << 'business' if :business
@post.tag_list << 'social' if :social
@post.tag_list << 'nature' if :nature
@post.tag_list << 'other' if :other
```

However when I do **post.tag_list** in the console I get the response of all of the tags **#=>'politics, tech, ... nature, other'**

Why isn't :business = false if I dont check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller should look like this.

```
@post.tag_list.clear
@post.tag_list << 'politics' if params[:post][:politics]
@post.tag_list << 'tech' if params[:post][:tech]
@post.tag_list << 'entertainment' if params[:post][:entertainment]
@post.tag_list << 'sports' if params[:post][:sports]
@post.tag_list << 'science' if params[:post][:science]
@post.tag_list << 'crime' if params[:post][:crime]
@post.tag_list << 'business' if params[:post][:business]
@post.tag_list << 'social' if params[:post][:social]
@post.tag_list << 'nature' if params[:post][:nature]
@post.tag_list << 'other' if params[:post][:other]
```

A symbol by itself will always evaluate to true. It's more like a constant than a variable. So it never has a value assigned to it.

Comment: Hmm, this still evaluates to all true

Comment: Could you look at your log and post the "Parameters:" line?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A9rDVezHQgMqKjspJYp7tSKjObT+hOVt4ycof0Fy6xE=", "post"=>{"title"=>"Title", "content"=>"Content", "politics"=>"1", "tech"=>"1", "entertainment"=>"0", "sports"=>"0", "science"=>"0", "crime"=>"0", "business"=>"0", "social"=>"0", "nature"=>"0", "other"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}